# Can PHP complete handshake if hostname and CN cert do not match?

Tags: php, san

I am facing a connection issue in my PHP program that was previously working.  It turns out the servers' tomcat cert was replaced with a SAN cert and the CN of the cert no longer matches the hostname.  The hostname is defined as a SAN entry, however I still cannot connect.  Even if defining a `cafile` to the cert, if fails.  Here is my script:

```
    <?php
    
    $host = "server_name";
    $username = "******";
    $password = "******";
    
    $context =
        stream_context_create(array('ssl'=>array('allow_self_signed'=>true)));
        
        $client = new SoapClient("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PhoneSetup\axl\AXLAPI.wsdl",
            array('trace'=>true,
           'exceptions'=>true,
           'location'=>"https://".$host.":8443/axl",
           'login'=>$username,
           'password'=>$password,
           'stream_context'=>$context
    
        ));
  
    $response = $client->getPhone(array("name"=>"SEP28AFFDA53393"));
    var_dump($response);
    
    
    ?>
```

I am using PHP 7.3 and do not see any updates to the `ssl` options so don't believe updating PHP will resolve this.  If anyone can provide any help I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: fails how? Are you getting a specific error? I'd suspect this is more of a general TLS question than anything specific to PHP

Comment: I get a 'cannot connect to host' error in the logs.  Running this same script that connects to a different server where the CN matches the hostname connects with no error.

Comment: I suppose you would have to set `verify_peer_name` to false, if you want to be able to make the connection regardless of the host name mismatch.

Comment: I added that as well but still getting the same result.

Comment: So it turns out adding the `verify_peer'=>false` option corrected this problem, however there still seems to be a potential problem with securing the connection when a SAN cert is used.

Comment: My only guesses are that either the cert is somehow incorrect, that some portion of the chain can't be validated, or that your OpenSSL is old. I just tried a really quick test `php -r "echo file_get_contents('https://office.com');"` and that worked. (The CN on that server is portal.office.com and office.com is a SAN.)

Comment: I will try adding the full chain to the pem file once I get a minute.  Thanks for the input.  For what it's worth, this is for Cisco Communications Manager.